# Copy DB table across 2 different MSSQL servers

Tags: sql-server, sql

I have 2 MSSQL servers running, with more or less the same data set. It is really a production/development setup.

Now, my workflow is like this. Every day backups are made of each one of the databases on the production server. I transfer the backups over the Internet (10s of Gigabytes) to the development server. I "restore" the database on the development server using the backup from the production server, so that I have a current data set.

My question is this:

Is there an easy and quick way to "export" a single table from a MSSQL server database and import it in a database in a different MSSQL server?

I am interested more in a "best practice" kind of operation, than some jury-rigged POS trick.

**UPDATE**

After some Googling around I found a function of the MSSQL Server that produces a script that exports the table and imports it when run. I cannot use this since I need to import the table in another Server.

Comment: What percentage, roughly, of that entire database, or better, that one table you are after, changes on a night per night basis? You are now transferring everything, but if only a part changes, you could export the table only on both the production and dev machine, then use something like rsync to transfer across only the differences. Then import that.

Comment: @JayMcTee This is indeed my issue. I want to only export/transfer/import a single table instead of a full DB backup file. My problem is, I do not know how to export/import a single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also fetch the data direct per SQL on your target Server. If you have network access:

```
SELECT a.*
INTO <YOUR TARGET TABLE>
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=<IP/SERVERNAME>;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'SELECT *
      FROM <YOUR TABLE>
      ') AS a;
```

But you must create the indexes by your self.

Or you using INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO 
<YOUR TARGET TABLE>
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=<IP/SERVERNAME>;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
         'SELECT *
          FROM <YOUR TABLE>
          ') AS a;
```

Answer (score 1):

The export part has been answered over at DBA:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25755/taking-a-backup-of-a-single-table-in-the-sql-server

How to export one single table on SQL server has been answered numerous times on Stackoverflow too:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680552/table-level-backup

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698310/backup-a-single-table-with-its-data-from-a-database-in-sql-server-2008

Google yields another many ways:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/923d1a5a-2f21-4193-9513-ab944145a58f/exporting-a-single-table-from-a-database

Once you have that export of a single table, transfer that by any means (rsync for example, or SFTP, scp) and then import it.